Calculating the matrix $[T]^B_{B}$
I'm trying to calculate the matrix $[T]^B_{B}$ where $B=\{ 1,x+1,x^{2}+1 \}$ and a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}_{2}[x]\to \mathbb{R}_{x}[x]$ by
$$
T(p(x))=p(x)-xp'(0)-x^{2}p''(0)
$$
I just tried mapping the basis to get three column vectors:
$$
[T(1)]_{B}=[1-0-0]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
[T(x+1)]_{B}=[x+1-x-0]_{B}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
[T(x^2+1)]_{B}=[x^2+1-(0)-2x^2]_{B}=[1-x^2]_{B}=??
$$
I'm not sure what I'm meant to get for the last one since $1-x^2$ isn't in $B$.
Is there any issue in my working? Or is there something I'm missing?

Your computations are fine. Since $1-x^2 = 2 - (x^2+1)$, one has $[1-x^2]_B = (2,0,-1)$ and thus $$[T]_B^B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 &  2 \ 0 & 0 & 0 \ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

can't believe I didn't think about that, thank you!

I'm putting Abezhiko's comment as an answer, so that the question is not un-answered:
Your computations are fine. Since $1−x^2=2−(x^2+1)$ one has $[1−x^2]_B=(2,0,−1)$
